# Cucumber - features for multi language site

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I'm new to cucumber and I'm trying to find the best way of defining a feature.

I need to test a site in multiple languages, so the feature I want to test is always the same but being the languages different the text I need to look for in the page might be different. This is roughly what I want to do:

```
Scenario Outline: Browse through category from the home page
    Given I am on the <country> home page
    When I browse categories
    Then I should get the browse category page

Examples:
     | country |
     | UK      |
     | IT      |
     | US      |
```

I haven't specified the **categories** values in the feature description itself, because:

1. I'd like to be able to read the **categories** from my DB, so whenever I add/remove one I don't need to modify the test itself
2. Imagine having 10 countries with 20 categories in the same feature file...it would be a mess
3. In order to avoid 2 I could create a feature file for each country...but then I'd have to copy and paste N times the same feature description

I thought about calling a step from another step as solution. Something like the following pseudocode:

```
When /^I browse categories$/ do
  on CURRENT_HOME_PAGE do |page|
     page.categories_list.each do |category|
        ....visit category page....
        ....call "Then I should get the browse category page" step...
        ....go back to CURRENT_HOME_PAGE....
     end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure this is the best best solution. Most people also deprecated calling steps from steps. I personally don't fancy it as well, since I don't like the idea to mixing up the step and feature definition.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling ruby methods instead of step defintions and using Cucumber instance variables?

I mean something like this:

```
Given /^I am on the (\w+) home page$/ do |country|
  @country = country # use Cucumber instance variable (it will be available in next steps of this scenario)
end

When /^I browse categories$/ do
  # read expected categories from DB for @country
  # visit Browse Categories page for @country
  # check that correct categories are shown
  expected_categories.each do |category|
    # visit category page
    # check that correct category page for @country is shown
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This sounds like what I needed. I have implemented a draft here: [link](https://github.com/barbasa/ui_testing) . Don't scream if you see crazy stuff in the code, I have just started with Ruby and Cucumber :)

Comment: Nothing...I just thought to post it in case somebody else had the same issue and wanted to see the whole implementation.